# c# get local path of .xsd from xsi:schemaLocation attribute value

Tags: c#, xml-parsing, xsd, schema

I am looking for a best way to exctract a local path of the schema without using regex.

Sample:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ord:order xmlns:ord="http://example.org/ord"
   xmlns:prod="http://example.org/prod"
   xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://example.org/prod chapter05prod.xsd
                   http://example.org/ord chapter05ord.xsd">
<items>
    <prod:product>
        <number xsi:type="xs:short">557</number>
        <name>Short-Sleeved Linen Blouse</name>
        <size xsi:nil="true"/>
    </prod:product>
</items>
```

or

```
xsi:schemaLocation="http://example.org/prod \\RandomFolder\New\chapter05prod.xsd">
```

or

```
 xsi:schemaLocation="chapter05prod.xsd">
```

I would like to get a local path for *.xsd file. Is there any way to do this using a xml parser or xmlResolver or in some other way that is not using a regex?

Edit: I am looking for a most generic approach to get a path for external .xsd path references.

Another example:

```
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="file://C://Documents and Settings//All Users//Application Data//My Application//MyData.xsd"
```

Comment: Note that the `noNamespaceSchemaLocation` requires a valid URI scheme, which is not the case in the last example you added above, since it contains an invalid path (you can't have double slashes in the path, only in the *hierarchical part* which precedes the path).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use XPath:

```
using System;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.XPath;
```

Since the data you want is inside an attribute that is qualified by a namespace, you would need to register the namespace before performing an XPath expression. In your case, you can *ignore the namespace* and use an expression like this one:

```
//@*[local-name()='schemaLocation']
```

which will select the attribute node which has a local name of `schemaLocation` (ignoring its prefix).

Parse your XML file and get the root (document) element:

```
XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader("your-file.xml");
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument(); 
doc.Load(reader);
reader.Close();
XmlElement root = doc.DocumentElement;
```

Then use it to select all attributes named `schemaLocation`. There is only one, so you can use `SelectSingleNode`:

```
XmlNode schemaLocationAttribute = root.SelectSingleNode("//@*[local-name()='schemaLocation']");
```

The expression above contains the attribute. You can get its string contents using `schemaLocationAttribute.Value`. From there you can split the contents using whitespace as the delimiter:

```
string[] components = schemaLocationAttribute.Value.Split(null);
```

And you will have the text that you want (`chapter05prod.xsd`) in `components[1]`:

```
Console.WriteLine (components[1]);
```

*(Note: you can't always ignore XPath namespaces - if there were other attributes named `schemaLocation` in your file with a different prefix or with no prefix, they would also be selected by that XPath expression and this solution would fail.)*

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Your solution seems useful in same cases. I will up vote this but I will wait a couple of more days for a more generic approach. If there won't be any then I will accept your answer. By the way I didn't know that the default value for string.split when passing null is whitespace. Right now I am using a Linq approach to get schemaLocation attribute then somehow extract the path. However the split method that you wrote is better then my regex try. However it will fail when there are spaces in path. Thanks.

Comment: Spaces shouldn't exist in a path when it's in a `schemaLocation` or `noNamespaceSchemaLocation` since a valid URI scheme requires them to be escaped (to `%20`). So a URL like: `file:///c:/My Directory/file.xsd` would be included as `file:///c:/My%20Directory/file.xsd`. Spaces as also significant in `schemaLocation` since they are used to separate each schema from its location, as well as the schema/location pairs.